# Bottom Scroll Checked acts in reverse

Tags: jquery

So I'm trying to detect if the page has scrolled all the way to the bottom, and I found this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       alert("bottom!");
    } 
});
```

And it works... in complete reverse! Instead of letting me know when I've scrolled all the way to the bottom, it detects when I've scrolled at the very top.

Would anyone tell me why it's doing that on my end?

Comment: lol just added "<!DOCTYPE html>" and everything went fine. im confused..

Answer (score 0):

This function is adding how far down you've scrolled `$(window).scrollTop()` to the height of your viewport `$(window).height()`. When it is greater or equal to the height of the webpage `$(document).height()`, it triggers the alert.

My guess is your webpage isn't higher than your viewport, so the alert message triggers at the top of your page. See this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6uAKH/)**. the function is working fine (view the console log) because the content of the page is taller than the viewport.